# ImportError: No module named 'deployment'

Tags: python, ubuntu

Not sure whether I should be posting this on askubuntu or here.
I am trying to perform object detection using Tensorflow. I am therefor following [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/JR8CmWyh2E8?t=709) (this link shows the exact issue I am facing).

When running [this script](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/train.py), I get this error:

```
$ python3 train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 51, in <module>
    from object_detection import trainer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/object_detection-0.1-py3.5.egg/object_detection/trainer.py", line 33, in <module>
    from deployment import model_deploy
ImportError: No module named 'deployment
```

According to the info I found online and the video I linked above I have to execute this command:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`/slim
```

While being in the `tensorflow/model/` directory. Yet, it doesn't solve my issue. And I don't really know what I should check in order to find out what is causing this persistent issue.

Could someone help me out?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

exactly what I do:

```
(tensorflow) xxx@yyy-ThinkPad-X200:~/Downloads/models/research/build/lib/object_detection$ cd ../../../../
(tensorflow) xxx@yyy-ThinkPad-X200:~/Downloads/models$ export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`/slim
(tensorflow) xxx@yyy-ThinkPad-X200:~/Downloads/models$ cd ~/Downloads/models/research/build/lib/object_detection
(tensorflow) xxx@yyy-ThinkPad-X200:~/Downloads/models/research/build/lib/object_detection$ python3 train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 51, in <module>
    from object_detection import trainer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/object_detection-0.1-py3.5.egg/object_detection/trainer.py", line 33, in <module>
    from deployment import model_deploy
ImportError: No module named 'deployment'
(tensorflow) xxx@yyy-ThinkPad-X200:~/Downloads/models/research/build/lib/object_detection$
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are installing from a clone of the tensorflow/models github you need to be inside models/research folder when you run the command:

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim
```

Notice the extra `` `pwd` `` to your command.

I still had problems until I ran from within models/research:

```
$ python setup.py build
$ python setup.py install
$ python slim/setup.py build
$ python slim/setup.py install
```

Note: In your case you may need to run `python3` instead of `python`.

Answer (score 3):

This work for me:

- Copy relevant deployment folder from the \models\slim directory
- paste it to Python\Lib\site-packages directory

then run again.It will work!

Answer (score 1):

It's `PYTHONPATH` not `PYTHONPAT`. You're missing `H` in your `export` statement.

Comment: My bad, that is just a typo in my main post. Corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

As of now, the slim folder has been moved to `models/research`. So if [models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models) is in the `/home` directory, do the following to resolve the issue:

1- Open the `~/.bashrc` and add the following line to the end of the file:

`export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/home/models:/home/models/research/slim/"`

3- Close the file and do `source ~/.bashrc`