# No module name deployment error while train the object detection model in google colab

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I am Malathi, I tried to train the object detection model using google colab. I got the error no module name deployment while training this model. but i train this same file in tensorflow-gpu it will work correctly.

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/h5py/__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 49, in <module>
    from object_detection import trainer
  File "/content/my_drive/tut_kaggle/zero/models/research/object_detection/trainer.py", line 33, in <module>
    from deployment import model_deploy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'deployment'
```

this is the code for training

```
!unset DISPLAY XAUTHORITY
!xvfb-run python3 train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config
```

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46758958/importerror-no-module-named-deployment) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to set the slim in PYTHONPATH. It should work.

```
%set_env PYTHONPATH=/content/models/research:/content/models/research/slim
```